# AC Cooling stops at high speed

Tags: chevrolet, ac, cooling-system, cooling

My car ac works very fine in normal conditions. But when I drive it for awhile longer, and often at high speed, it stops cooling. I can still hear the fan sound loud and clear but air flow decreases a lot even at full speed of blower.
My car is Chevrolet beat diesel 2011 model.

Comment: Has the ac been recharged recently?  If it is overcharged, it may be detecting too high a pressure and so shutting down.

Comment: when i decrease speed of car air flow gets back to normal and with full cooling .

Comment: AC is not recharged since i got this vehicle.

Comment: @HandyHowie tell me if there could be a problem in my ac?

Comment: This might shed some light on your problem: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18949/a-c-does-not-cool-when-speeding-more-than-100kmph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently it was a long piece of paper carried into fan assembly by a mouse. After running for a while paper must be choking the fan and thus stopping the air flow. Thanks everybody.